# Increase Drop down for orders and products

Tags: magento

There are a few answers to this and i followed this

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml

change

```
<option value="100"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==100): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100</option>
```

to

```
<option value="1000"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==1000): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>1000</option>
```

Refreshed cache, reindexed logged in logged out yet still doesnt change.

Any suggestions?

In admin grid i want to have the option to show more orders rather than the standard max of 200.

Comment: What  is the issue? and what you want to do?

Comment: In admin grid i want to have the option to show more orders rather than the standard max of 200.

Comment: So post this to you question

Comment: this is the tutorial

http://www.magentothemess.com/archives/1090

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the link to magentothemess archive is a correct solution. I have done this myself as I work on a store with 100,xxx sku count. However be careful, I experienced extreme failure to return values after increasing the limit to 400 or so. Even 300 sometimes would drop results. Conclusion while this can be done it seems to uncover a deeper issue within magento's adminhtml grid setup. Just to note I am on EE 1.14.

Comment: Cheers Chris

Doesnt work at all for me, had a lot of custom work done so might be that, will try with random number in between to see if that works.

Comment: well if you have directories in adminhtml other than default/default then check your config to verify fallback order and make sure that the file wasn't completely copied over, which would make your edits never looked at by magento

Comment: changed to 25 but still no joy cleared cache and reindexed as well

Comment: what does your directory 'app/design/adminhtml' look like? if you have any other directories other than 'default' in the list, chances are magento is not even looking at the file you are editing.

Comment: /httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget          

adminhtml has frontend and install - no other folders when going through default default

Comment: ok so we don't have a design override. Look through 'app/code/local/' and 'app/code/community' to see if any of your customizations deal with the adminhtml/widget

Comment: ok i have a folder adminhtml in code/local but it has no code in it suggesting the drop down. Is there anyway to look at the admin page and find what file is being called.

Comment: well just to test if that code is causing this issue. go to system>configuration>advanced>advanced in your admin panel and disable the module containing the adminhtml folder...also you could find the app/etc/module xml and change the active tag to false...once you have done either of these try to change the dropdown again...if it works your custom code/local module is overriding the widget behavior. After this I am out of ideas.